# What is the Wildcat in Kingdom Rush?

Tags: kingdom-rush

I've noticed in a few levels I've had this small cat attacking enemies. It's called the wildcat and I'm not sure where it comes from. Can anyone tell me what it is? Is it a spawn from my hero, Alleria? Is it a byproduct of a tower specialty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wildcat is spawned by Alleria's ability, Call of the Wild. It's a melee unit that will follow Alleria and attack with her.